# use different beans implementation relying on a variable in the configuration file

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have 2 beans:

```
@Component("FierstClient")
public class FierstClient implements CryptoClient {
```

and

```
@Component("SecondClient")
public class SecondClient implements CryptoClient {
```

And I have service:

```
    @Component
    public class CryptoServiceImpl implements CryptoService {

        private final Marshaler marshaler;
        private final CryptoClient cryptoClient;

        public CryptoServiceImpl(Marshaler marshaler, 
                                 @Qualifier("FirstClient") CryptoClient cryptoClient) {
            this.marshaler = marshaler;
            this.cryptoClient = cryptoClient;
        }
```

Now I have a task - move to control of this beans config file. I know some solutions, but they seem naive to me:

1. Create config `default-server: first // or second` and in `CryptoServiceImpl` inject 2 beans:

   @Qualifier("FirstClient") CryptoClient cryptoClientFirst
   @Qualifier("SecondsClient") CryptoClient cryptoClientSecond

and when I use it write:

```
if(default-server equals first)...else...
```

2. Create `Profile`. But will I have  another configs like DB and etc. Ans I will have many profuiles with combinations like:

> FirstClientAndPosgresqlProfile 
>   FirstClientAndOracleProfile
>   SecondClientAndPosgresqlProfile 
>   SecondClientAndOracleProfile

...

and if I will have more changeable parameters I will have new profiles?

may exist clear solution for use different beans implementation relying on a variable in the configuration file?

Comment: *move to control of this beans config file* - what? can you be a bit more specific?

Comment: @Eugene I change parameter in config file and my server use fierst bean/ I change parameter and my server use second bean

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use something like this

```
@Configuration
public class ClientConfig {

    @Bean(name="criptoClient")
    @ConditionalOnProperty(
      name = "enabled.client", 
      havingValue = "first")
    public CryptoClient firstClient() {
        // return first client
    }

    @Bean(name="criptoClient")
    @ConditionalOnProperty(
      name = "enabled.client",
      havingValue = "second")
    public CryptoClient secondClient() {
        // return second client
    }

    @Bean(name="criptoClient")
    @ConditionalOnProperty(
      name = "enabled.client", 
      matchIfMissing = true)
    public CryptoClient defaultClient() {
        // return default client
    }
}
```

You need to set the `enable.client` property to either `first` or `second`. If the property is not present `DefaultClient` gets instantiated.

Another approach would be to move the `@ConditionalOnProperty` on top of your `@Component` definitions. In this case you would no longer need the above `@Configuration`.

```
@Component("criptoClient")
@ConditionalOnProperty(
      name = "enabled.client", 
      havingValue = "first")
public class FierstClient implements CryptoClient {
}

@Component("criptoClient")
@ConditionalOnProperty(
      name = "enabled.client",
      havingValue = "second")
public class SecondClient implements CryptoClient {
}
```

Comment: Ok, I tried this solutionbut how can I inject CryptoClient to my service? I have warning:Could not autowire. There is more than one bean of 'FirstClient' type.
Beans:
firstClientImpl   (FirstClientImpl.java) secondClient   (SecondClient.java)

Comment: what is your value for the `enabled.client`? Also, have you remove your old definitions with `@Component`?

Comment: I have 2 beans with `@Component` annotations. I think I fix this problem. I add `@ConditionalOnProperty` annotation under `@Component` annotation and write same names for beans - `@Component("criptoClient) `for first and  `@Component("criptoClient)` for second

Comment: Yes, you can either move the `@ConditionalOnProperty` annotation there or remove the `@Component` annotations and rely entirely on the configuration for bean definitions.

Comment: if I delete the annotation `@Component` in any case, all beans must have the same name. You can complete your answer and I will accept it as correct.

Comment: Updated answer. I guess you are using @Qualifier, right?

Comment: Yes, I used. and then there were several ways. 1. do not use `@Qualifier` - then the spring swore that there are several implementations. 2. use `@Qualifier` - but it does not suit me. so I removed the `@Qualifier` and called the beans with the same name